# Greater than, less than - multiple solutions

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search Column V (called TotalWeight).

If it's under 100 then in Column W it will say "L"
between 101 - 250 "H"
between 250 - 500 "VH"
Over 500 "VVH"

I tried

```vb
Sub Change_Weight()

    =IF([TotalWeight]0 > 100, “L”, IF([TotalWeight]101 > 250, “H”, IF([TotalWeight]250 > 500, “VH”, IF([TotalWeight]500 > 900, “VVH”))))

End Sub
```

Comment: Start by reading the MS Help page on If Then Else End If.  Place your cursor on the If and press F1.  Then you should read up on Select Case statements.  Particularly the option to specify a range for a Case (e.g. x To Y).

Comment: Are you looking for VBA code or an Excel formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest, is to put your conditions into a separate table. Any time your boss wants different values or wants more conditions it is much easier to maintain that list than to change the formula.

Put this formula into Column V:

```
=INDEX(configTotalWeight[Description],MATCH(A3,configTotalWeight[TotalWeight],1))
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yRmXvsJ.png]

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to work backwards from the heaviest weight to the lightest, with the lightest being the last 'False' result, so:

```
=If([TotalWeight]>500,"VVH",IF([TotalWeight]>250,"VH",IF([TotalWeight]>100,"H","L")))
```